# Swift - RootPageViewController, add buttons from different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I've got my **RootPageViewController** set up and all I need is to add `UIButtons`. I've already added the button and its function from the `UIViewController` which is to be displayed first.

How am I able to also add `UIButtons` from f.e. the third `UIViewController` and assign them a function?
Just like with the button from the **secondViewController** which is displayed first: `secondViewController.buttonAdd.action = #selector(addData(_:))`

If I solely use let's say `firstViewController.buttonBack.action = #selector(backData(_:))` - I'll get an error saying:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

I assume thats because, there's no `if let firstViewController ...`

But let's say I'd add:

```
if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first as? TimelineViewController {
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            firstViewController.buttonBack.action = #selector(backData(_:))
        }
```

In this case the order which view will be shown initially and which next etc. will be mixed up.

I'm open for suggestion and better approaches, I just want this to work,

**RootPageViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timelineView")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView")
        let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addView")

        return [vc1, vc2, vc3]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        if let secondViewController = viewControllerList[1] as? MainViewController {
            self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            secondViewController.buttonAdd.action = #selector(addData(_:))
        }
    }

    @objc func addData(_ sender: Any) {
        if let thirdViewController = viewControllerList.last {
            self.setViewControllers([thirdViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func backData(_ sender: Any) {
        let secondViewController = viewControllerList[1]
        self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to call this in any `UIViewControllers` button action:

```
// get parent view controller
    let parentVC = self.parent as! UserDetailsPVC

    // change page of PageViewController
    parentVC.setViewControllers([parentVC.pages[1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```